# Detect WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK on a button of Toolbar

Tags: winapi, mfc, window

How can we detect `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` on a button (ex. `ID_FILE_NEW`) on a Toolbar?

Comment: I curious. Why do you want to circumvent the use of an event handler?

Comment: This kind of strange UI feature is a bad idea IMO. Do you want to distinguish between a simple click and a double click on the button?

Comment: I also wondered why this was needed.

Comment: @ Wished feature: With ID_FILE_NEW you erase (not delete) the existing document. If you deleted it by accident or changed the opinion you can comeback with an Restore Command. IF DoubleClick on ID_FILE_NEW this is definitely deleted I

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes I want to distinguish between simple click and a DoubleClick on a Toolbar button.  How to achieve this without PreTransalteMessage()?

Comment: @TomTom I have no idea how to do this, but as mentioned before it looks liek a very bad idea from the users inferface perspective.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, this is not the usual way. The standard way is: before deleting the document, let the user the choice if he want  to save or erase the document. Ok, make it simply but not simpler. The right way is a separate 'Erase All' button right from the New button?

Comment: @TomTom I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want but having a double clic on an icon act differently from a simple clic on that same icon is a very poor user experience. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be straight forward with `PreTranslateMessage()`. I have tested with this code snippet.

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // Detect Clicks in Toolbar detektieren
    if (pMsg->hwnd == m_wndToolBar.GetSafeHwnd())
    {
        if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            CPoint pt = pMsg->pt;
            m_wndToolBar.ScreenToClient(&pt);

            int nIdx = m_wndToolBar.CommandToIndex(ID_FILE_NEW);
            CRect rcIdx;
            m_wndToolBar.GetItemRect(nIdx, &rcIdx);
            if (rcIdx.PtInRect(pt))
            {
                MessageBox(_T("yupii double click detected"));
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return CMDIFrameWndEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```